# Change startdate according to an other date chosen

Tags: aurelia, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a simple view with 2 components aurelia-date-picker [aurelia-date-picker github](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aurelia-bootstrap-datepicker)
When I choose a date in the first one, in the second calendar I don't want dates before the chosen date to be selected.
My HTML :

```
<template>
<require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
<form>
  Date début: <bootstrap-datepicker dp-options.bind="dpOptions1" changedate.delegate="setDateDebut($event)"></bootstrap-datepicker>
  Date de fin: <bootstrap-datepicker id="datefin" dp-options.bind="dpOptions2" changedate.delegate="setDateFin($event)">     </bootstrap-datepicker>
 </form>
 </div
</template>
```

My view-model :

```
export class ChoixDateDebutDateFin {
  constructor(cd, abdp){
  this.dpOptions1={
  format:"dd/mm/yyyy",
  autoclose:true,
  calendarWeeks:true,
  language:"fr-FR",
  todayHighlight:true,
  weekStart:1
}
this.dpOptions2={
  format:"dd/mm/yyyy",
  autoclose:true,
  calendarWeeks:true,
  language:"fr-FR",
  todayHighlight:true,
  weekStart:1
}
setDateDebut(e){
  var d=e.detail.event.date;
  console.log("d ?"+d);
//Here ! I want to change dynamically the property stratdate :(
  this.dpOptions2.startDate=d;
}
setDateFin(event){
  this.fin=event.detail.date;
}
}
```

For sure, it doesn't work since the component is loaded at startup, so it won't consult its options again.
So the question is :

either => how to force it to reload options ?

or => how to disable dates before a given date after startup ?

Comment: I believe [bind](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-binding-behaviors/1) will help you out with this one!

Comment: Well, the thing is my aurelia-bootstrap-datepicker is not bound. So I don't see any way to add `& signal:'need-update'` somewhere in my HTML template ...

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is here:
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/methods.html#setstartdate

You want to change the line of code after your comment to:

```
document.getElementById("datefin").setStartDate(d);
```

Or if you're using JQuery, this is even easier:

```
$('#datefin').setStartDate(d);
```

Comment: Correct syntaxe is `$('#datefin').datepicker('setStartDate',d);`. But 1: this put a new div calendar in my DOM, right after the previous one :(.But 2: I wished I could have done it more in an "Aurelia way", Meaning no JQUERY or DOM manipulation....

Comment: And in order NOT to have 2 div datepicker, I did : `$('#datefin').find('.datepicker').datepicker('setStartDate',d);` and it works. But, again, if someone have an idea how to do it without Jquery and with Aurelia mecanisms, it would be very pedagogic and interesting :)